# Vue Route does not working. Laravel 8 + Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I don't know what's wrong with my code or it issues on laravel 8?

**router JS File**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import FirstPage from './components/pages/FirstPage.vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    { path: '/new-route', component: FirstPage }
]

export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})
```

**app JS File**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue')

import router from './router'

Vue.component('mainapp', require('./components/mainapp.vue').default)

const app = new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    router
})
```

**web PHP File**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('test', [TestController::class, 'test']);

Route::any('{slug}', function(){
    return view ('error');
});
```

does any have an idea? or any suggestions. (It requires more details to be posted)

Comment: what is you `web.php` config .? or remove `mode: 'history',` and where is `<router-view>` ?

Comment: <router-view> is in mainapp.vue component

Comment: when i remove history,  it works  fine but with # on url, how can I remove hashtag?

Comment: ohh then it is issue of `web.php` can you put that code ?

Comment: already include my code above, please see thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use this in `web.php`

```php
Route::any('{all}', [TestController::class, 'test'])
    ->where('all', '^(?!api).*$')
    ->where('all', '^(?!storage).*$');
```

---

or

```php
Route::any('{all}',function(){
    return view('main'); // it should be main blade file 
})
->where('all', '^(?!api).*$')
->where('all', '^(?!storage).*$');
```

to work vue router without `#`

this code exclude `api` and `storage` url so both will work and other all route catch so vuejs do its magic

Comment: how about the mode: 'history'? so it doesnt need anymore?

Comment: route doesnt work but without error when i use your code above.

Comment: the first one, it appears error 404

Comment: did you removed all route in `web.php` and only keep my code

Comment: oh i see, now its working :), thank you @Kamlesh

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it fixed

Comment: how do i mark this as fix? Sorry Im newbee here

Comment: @Marc any right mark did you see in this answer you need to click that

Comment: You save my life bro. @Marc flag this answer as correct!